Counting check boxes in formula only if cell is not empty
I am trying to create a habit tracker and have check boxes. I have inserted them fine but I would like to figure (as a fraction) to show the amount of habits completed. This currently shows how many check boxes ticked / total amount of check boxes (ticked and not ticked). However, I would like this to show amount of check boxes ticked / total amount of check boxes (ticked or unticked) where there is next is the cell to the left.
For example, the habits are shown in Cells B13:D28 and the amount of habits completed v total is in cells B35:D35.
Which formula can I use to get the completion figure to only count tick boxes (checked and unchecked) where there is a habit included in the same row? From the example picture and data included the completion figure should show ‘124/124’ instead of ‘124/496’

Hope this makes sense.
I have currently used the following formula
=countif(E13:AI28,true)&"/"&counta(E13:AI28)

but this hasn’t worked


You may try:
=let(Σ,filter(E13:AI28,len(B13:B28)),
     countif(Σ,true)&"/"&counta(Σ))


amazing, this worked perfectly. How do I now get a pie chart to show complete vs incomplete tasks from this formula?

Count ticked checkbox over total number of checkbox
You can also try this approach, this effectively check the number of ticked checkboxes over the total number of checkboxes(ticked or not) but only if there is a "habit" associated with a row.
Formula used:
=COUNTIF(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(B1:F7, countif(A1:A7, "<>"),COUNTIF(B1:F1, "<>")),"=TRUE")&"/"& COUNTA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(B1:F7, countif(A1:A7, "<>"),COUNTIF(B1:F1, "<>")))

Sample Output
With 4 tasks

With 5 tasks

Disclaimer:
This answer uses a personal sheet and data, adjust the ranges according to your needs
Change the following according to your needs:
Range B1:F7 is the range that contains all the checkboxes(ticked or not)
Range A1:A7 is the range that contains the 'Habits'
Range B1:F1 This helps to determine the number of columns to include when constraining the range in ARRAY_CONSTRAIN
Special note
Borrowing idea from @rockinfreakshow's approach, you can also try this
=LET(x, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(B1:F7, countif(A1:A7, "<>"),COUNTIF(B1:F1, "<>")), COUNTIF(x, "=TRUE")&"/"&COUNTA(x))

References: COUNTIF, COUNTA, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN
